# Meteor AutoForm: form with id "asdf" needs either "schema" or "collection" attribute

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-autoform

I have an autoform that I want to render using a schema. I have the schema returned by a helper template in Template.name.helpers({:

```
Template.name.helpers({
  getSchema: function() {
    var schema = new SimpleSchema({
      location: {
        type: String,
        label: "Start location"
      }
    });
    return schema;
  }
```

html:

```
{{#autoForm schema=getSchema id="submitOfferLift" type="method"}}
```

However I can't get the helper to work ([relevant docs](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform#should-the-value-of-schema-and-collection-have-quotation-marks-around-it)). In addition, if I just define `schema = {...}` in template.js and specify `schema = "schema"` in the autoform, I get a message saying that schema is not defined in the window scope. Furthermore, if I create the schema variable in the console, the form renders just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your helper is returning a simple object whereas it should have been returning a SimpleSchema instance

```
Template.name.helpers({
  getSchema: function() {
    var schema = new SimpleSchema({
      location: {
        type: String,
        label: "Start location"
      })
      return schema;
  }
})
```

Also, the template inclusion should use `>` instead of `#`

```
{{> autoForm schema=getSchema id="submitOfferLift" type="method"}}
```

Comment: Oops, I actually had that originally, which also didn't work. I took out the `new SimpleSchema` to see if that would work and just copied and pasted that into my question without reverting the change. Edited the question to reflect that.